# NodeJS: installing dependencies from package.json located one level above the working folder

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

The project I need to work upon is structured in a way that the package.json file is one level abov the code folder. The code is located at "D:\MyNodeProj\Source\"

All the files and code is located under "Source" project including "node_modules" folder. Package.json file is located out of "Source" folder. It is located at "D:\MyNodeProj\package.json" When I try to run the project it gives an error: Cannot find module 'winston-logzio'

I know this has something to do with package.json's location as winston-logzio's entry is there in package.json

I tried npm install but it is also throwing error. It used to work before when package.json and node_modules folder were on same level. Now that package.json is one level up we are haviing all sorts of trouble.

What is the fix for this? **Please note, we can not change the location of package.json now** Don't know for what reason but the architect want it this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use prefix for the parent directory, you will be able to use `npm install --prefix=./../` in the project folder (`D:\MyNodeProj\Source\`), this command will install node_modules in the parent directory(`D:\MyNodeProj\`). But in order to make the node_module visible to your project you can set `NODE_PATH` to the parent directory and then run the project.

Comment: Yeah I did that but the thing is after installing node_modules in parent directory, I still get 'No such file or directory' exception for package.json because it is also in parent directory.

Comment: If you mean you can not use npm install after setting the enviroment variable, In the commands like `npm install` that needs `package.json`  you can use `NODE_PATH=.` before the command to set `NODE_PATH` just for that command. e.g `NODE_PATH=. npm install --prefix=./../`